# How to overwrite a particular line in flat file?

Tags: php, text

My text file contains:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I can't figure out how to amend my code so that I can overwrite line 3 ONLY (ie replacing "c") with whatever I type into the input box 'data'. My code is as follows, currently the contents of the input box 'data' replaces my file entirely:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$file = "data.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "w") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing");

fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file"); 
fclose($fp);
```

I have it working the other way around, ie the code below reads line 3 ONLY into the text box when the page first loads:

```
$file = "data.txt";
$lines = file( $file ); 
echo stripslashes($lines[2]);
```

Can anybody advise the code I need to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The only way is to read the whole file, change the 3rd line, then write it all back out. Basically, like so:

```
$lines = file($file);
$lines[2] = $_POST['data'];
file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $lines));
```

Btw, your reading code does not "ONLY" read line 3 - it reads all lines as per file() and then you only use line 3.

Comment: "*The only way*" should read "*Because you don't store/remember the position in the file, the only way*"; using `fseek()` you can jump to a position in the file and overwrite and/or append from that position (without the need to read the whole file).

Comment: You can use seek only if the replacement line is the exact length of the existing line, which for textual data is unlikely. But sure, if you have fixed length records, seeking makes sense...but then you're reinventing a database.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am a little confused - are you suggesting to work this into the writing code or into the reading code? I have tried both but it is still writing all of the contents of the input box to the text file.

Comment: That is the entire writing code - first it reads in all lines, then changes the array's 3rd element, then writes it all back out. There is no change to the reading code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work :/... if I upload "data.txt" containing a, b, c etc all on unique lines, I load the page and I can see "c" only in the text box which is correct, if I change this to "CCCCCC" and hit save then look at the text file all it contains is "CCCCCC". I have commented out my original fwrite code... any ideas?